dd runs >30h on 32GB USB stick
I have a USB stick which I want to reformat on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. In lsblk it looks like this:
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                           8:0    1  29.4G  0 disk  

First, I tried to just use sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sda, but it fails with mkfs.vfat: failed whilst writing reserved sector. So, I followed answers such as How to format a USB stick and executed
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=2048 count=32 && sync
(I also tried with bs=4M and no count).
However, this command runs forever (I let it run for about 30h).
It seems dd gets stuck somewhere.
Is there a way to fix this?
Anamnesis of the USB stick
Earlier I tried to create a bootable medium from it using a Windows. The app always returned some generic error, but I tried a few times.

might it be easier to use the Disks utility (press the Super key and type disks), identify which is your USB drive, click on the cog wheel icon and select Format Partition ?

Start gparted.
Access your USB.
Erase the partition table if it exists.
Create a msdos partition table.
Create a primary partition, ext4 file system

Disks errors with failed to probe device, GParted doesn't even see the USB drive

If the device is still good, maybe use a partition tool to put a partition table on it, make a partition (sda1), and format the partition.  Search this site for "slow copy" or transfer rate and see the problems of writing to a slow device when system buffers fill up.
